# how to get this result in sql?

Tags: sql

Here is the DB available.

```
create table tab1 (
  masterid integer(2) primary key,
  name varchar(22),
  l2 integer(2)
);

insert into tab1 values(1,'g-1',50);
insert into tab1 values(2,'g-1',50);
insert into tab1 values(3,'g-1',50);
insert into tab1 values(50,'grup1',-1);
insert into tab1 values(5,'g-1',50);
insert into tab1 values(60,'grup2',-1);
insert into tab1 values(7,'g-2',60);
insert into tab1 values(8,'g-2',60);
```

Also available on: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7fe9/1

Result should be groupwise. For example, Row 50,grup1,-1 is having 50 which will work as primary key and whichever row has that masterID( herein case 50) in l2 column , that should be retrieved.So Basically so I want following output.

```
MasterId    Name    l2  
   50       grup1   -1
   1        g-11    50
   2        g-12    50
   3        g-13    50
   5        g-14    50
   60       grup2   -1
   7        g-21    60
   8        g-22    60
```

Note that All the group will have -1 value in L2 column.
I have tried many things but I am confused this output can be achieved or not.I will appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: And what would `g-213` mean? The 13th subgroup of group-2 or the 3rd subgroup of group-21?

Comment: @ypercube sir, this was random data...not a real one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab1
-- Order records by "master id groups", first
ORDER BY CASE WHEN l2 = -1 THEN Masterid ELSE l2 END,
-- Within a "master id group", get the master first and then its children
         CASE WHEN l2 = -1 THEN 0        ELSE 1 END
```

Optionally, you can amend more expressions to the `ORDER BY` clause, to order "siblings"

Answer (score 0):

Better would be to normalize the data into a group table, and use l2 as a foreign key.  You might not get the output you are asking for, but you can write your code to use the group data to do what you need to with the data.

```
create table groups (
  masterid integer(2) primary key,
  name varchar(22),
);
create table tab1 (
  masterid integer(2) primary key,
  name varchar(22),
  l2 integer(2)
);

insert into groups values(50,'grup1');
insert into groups values(60,'grup2');
insert into tab1 values(1,'g-1',50);
insert into tab1 values(2,'g-1',50);
insert into tab1 values(3,'g-1',50);
insert into tab1 values(5,'g-1',50);
insert into tab1 values(7,'g-2',60);
insert into tab1 values(8,'g-2',60);
```